# How to populate a DBComboBox control from a table in Delphi 7?

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7

The programming environment is Delphi 7, the DBMS is MySQL.

I have this table definition:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS language;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS language (
    language_id   TINYINT       NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
    language      VARCHAR(16)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (language_id),
    UNIQUE       (language)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now, how do I go about populating a **DBComboBox** with data from the language table in such a way that the user can't see the **language_id** column but it's there and I can use it? But it may as well be just a ComboBox.

Comment: read this http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/Using+Data-Aware+Controls/. and put the Language_id field property visible to false.

Comment: Okay, how do I set the language_id field's visibility to false? And how can I check programmatically which language_id is currently chosen?

Comment: Are you sure that you want a dbComboBox as opposed to a dbLookupComboBox? The latter allows one to set a displayed value (listfield - this would be the 'language' field in your table) as well as a non-displayed key value (keyfield, 'language_id').

Comment: @rba Why not an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You need to fill it via its `Items` property. The chosen item is used as a field value.

What you probably want is a lookup combobox. It's called `TDBLookupComboBox`. You should be able to get it working once you find that one.

Comment: Not that Items is of type `TStrings` which is able to store an object for every Item. You can access the objects using `Items.Objects[I]`, but normally you'd use a `TDBLookupComboBox` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above, some simple example code is as per :

```
with MyDataSource1.DataSet
do begin
   Open;
   DBComboBox1.Properties.Items.clear;
   while not EOF do begin
       DBComboBox1.Properties.Items.Add(fieldbyname('language').asstring);
       next;
   end;
end;
```